# How do I retrieve items under "The Warrior" 's skin?

Tags: borderlands-2

On one of my accounts, I killed "The Warrior". As usual, there was a little cinematic and "The Warrior" blew up as usual, leaving is skin behind. However, under that massive hunk of skin, I found a legendary weapon. Namely, the Liquid Pitchfork.

I tried everything I knew:

- I attempted to crawl under the skin
- I tried to stand right on top of the item
- Killed Handsome Jack in hopes that "The Warrior's" body will disappear

So, is there a way to retrieve an item underneath "The Warrior's" skin? Or is it impossible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An update from yesterday now drags the Warrior's body into the pit once you kill him, allowing you to grab loot that would've been otherwise impossible to obtain:

From portions of the [patch notes:](http://support.gearboxsoftware.com/entries/22126761--PC-Update-Hot-Fix-Information%5D)

> - Disabled the daily lockout for raid bosses
> - **Shoved The Warrior off into the abyss after he dies so that players can always grab loot    that he might otherwise have been
>     sitting on.**
> - Addressed an issue that could cause players to lose control of their characters when using certain telescopes simultaneously in a multiplayer game.